# OAuth2: What is the "client"?

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0

When using OAuth2 system in an API we talk about `client_id` and `client_secret`. **What exactly is a client?** Is it a person/user? Or is it the platform? iPhone, Android, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client in most cases is the App.

In OAuth you have 3 roles, `ServiceProvider`, `ResourceOwner` and `Client`. There is also an additional role for Authorization server but for most implementations AuthServer and ServiceProvider are both the same.

I can give you an example that will help you understand better.

- Take the app 'Tweetdeck' that you want to use to post tweets onto your Twitter account.
- Here, Tweetdeck is a client, You are resource owner and Twitter is the ServiceProvider and AuthServer.
- Tweetdeck(Client) will need your permission(login) to access your Twitter Account (Resources) on Twitter(Service Provider).
- So the Tweekdeck team will signup with Twitter for a Client Account for which Twitter issues them a client_id and client_secret.

OAuth is a specification that standardizes this interaction.

Answer (score 0):

The client is a computer/device which sends requests to the server.  The server responds to the clients requests.